# Nested references between database projects in SSDT cannot be resolved

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I'm currently creating a huge database solution with over 40 projects and tons of references.

It's a very common situation that project A references project B, then project B references project C and so on like this:

A->B->C->D

When I'm trying to build project D it's all working correctly. Same for project C, it resolves reference to D and builds successfully.

When I try to build project B I get an error like this:

***The reference to external elements from the source named D.dacpac' could not be resolved, because no such source is loaded.***

I'm sure that all references are set up and nothing is missing. My dacpacs are stored for each project in bin/Debug folder.

Please help me with some hints or ideas on how to continue my investigation.

Comment: You can't use 3/4 parts naming in SSDT without using variables. Check my comment here how to organize the project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289174/sql-deployment-automation/56297914#56297914 . You can also can check example solution in my git repo: https://github.com/dkultasev/SSDTPowerTemplate

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev , I am already using variables for database names

Comment: Project B should include reference to D as well

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Thank you! Could you please explain in more detail why I need to add those 'transitive references', or maybe share some link? I thought Visual Studio would pick them up automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately such great tool as SSDT is very poorly documented. I can try to explain how do I understand that: when you reference db C, it has objects from D and SSDT is trying to get meta data for them as well, to be able to validate everything properly. Additionally what you can try to do is to tick the "Suppress errors caused by unresolved references in the referenced project" when adding reference for the project C. That might work as well.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev, thank you, adding those references fixed my issue. I really miss proper SSDT documentation, just blindly trying to do something and then learn from mistakes. Could you please help me with another issue? I'm adding just one reference to system databases, it works well. And after some time I start receiving errors about incorrect reference. I go to the references section and see this: https://pasteboard.co/JqzDSDh.png

Comment: Working with SSDT requires to get familiar with some nuances... Please rename following question title to something like: "Reference to external elements problem with nested database references". The key word here is "nested". For another question, please create separate question and I'll answer there. It might help others as well.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev, thank you! I have created a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63849710/reference-to-system-databases-becomes-duplicated-in-ssdt-database-project

Answer (score 0):

Even do I've answered in the comments already, it might be helpful for other with similar problem.

The solution is: you need to add reference to parent project of all other dacpacs. So in your case `project B` should have reference for **both** `C` and `D` projects.

Another possible option would be to tick the "Reference to external elements problem with nested database references" checkbox when you add reference to `C` project, but that's not always work.