# Reference to system databases becomes duplicated in SSDT database project

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

In a huge SSDT database solution with lots of projects and references, I'm adding a reference from my project to system databases(master, msdb), it works well, and the build is successful.

And after some time I start receiving errors about incorrect reference. I go to the references section and see this: https://pasteboard.co/JqzDSDh.png

I tried removing the second reference and the errors were gone but then this issue comes back and I see two identical references again.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question and add embedded image rather than adding the link.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably something is wrong with your `project.sqlproj` file. Try to search `master.dacpac` keyword there and make sure that there is no multiple entries. Make sure that dacpac path is not fully hardcoded, but uses `$(DacPacRootPath)` variable there.

This is an example how the reference should look like (make sure that you have the right SQL version defined in the path. Mine one is 140 here).

```
    <ArtifactReference Include="$(DacPacRootPath)\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\140\SqlSchemas\master.dacpac">
      <HintPath>$(DacPacRootPath)\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\140\SqlSchemas\master.dacpac</HintPath>
      <SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>False</SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>
      <DatabaseVariableLiteralValue>master</DatabaseVariableLiteralValue>
    </ArtifactReference>
```

If that wouldn't help, try to run "Clean Solution", then delete all `*.jfm` files and `*.dbmdl` files, `bin` and `obj` folders and re-build the project.

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to set value for $(DacPacRootPath) anywhere? I believe modifying the XML is the only way to have that path with variable inside, right?

Comment: It is built-in variable, you don't need to set it anywhere