# Database Project with table references error

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I have a database that sits on a server with a few stored procedures that reference tables in the other databases.

This results in an error when I try build my SSDT projects as the tables don't exist in the database I am importing. Now the thing is I just want to import the required tables and not the entire database, how do I do this?

Comment: You can add [database references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/add-database-reference-dialog-box?view=sql-server-ver16) to objects in other tables or actual databases

Comment: That requires me to either have a dacpac or another project in my solution with all the objects from that database

Comment: I dont want to have to import the whole other database or have to manually select each table

Comment: You can add references to actual databases without importing them into a project. You can't just ignore tables in other databases. When SSDT compiles the project into a DACPAC or generates a script it checks the metadata for everything.

Comment: I dont have the permissions to create a DACPAC from that database

Comment: Did you check the docs? Did you *try* to add a reference to a database with the wizard?

Comment: If you scroll down you own question, you'll find related questions. There are lots of similar questions. There is my detailed answer how to handle that properly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289174/sql-deployment-automation/56297914#56297914